# i would like to ask about Mysql Select with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which is session, and has a session_id, another tables which are namespmember1, namespmember2, namespmember3

Everytime i save the form which has the session table, namespmember1, namespmember2, namespmember3. They are all save also. which there ID's are equal becuase they are save as batch.

my question is. i want to edit those tables or view... heres my code which is redundant and i guess there is a solution for it.

Im getting the ID for the session table.

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM session WHERE session_id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($q);
```

And now i will display the tables namespmember1, namespmember2, namespmember3

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namespmember1 WHERE hon1_id='$id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row->spmember_name</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->present</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->absent</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->leave_sick</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->business</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namespmember2 WHERE hon2_id='$id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row->spmember_name</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->present</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->absent</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->leave_sick</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->business</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM namespmember3 WHERE hon3_id='$id'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>$row->spmember_name</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->present</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->absent</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->leave_sick</td>";
    echo "<td>$row->business</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

session_id is equal to all the ids in differnt tables namespmember1, namespmember2, namespmember3

Thank you for the help.

Comment: First of all, you need to tell us more about your actual data model. How does the data in tables namespmember1, namespmember2 and namespmember3 differ in its structure f.e.?

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM session s,namespmember1 n1,
    namespmember2 n2,namespmember3 n3 WHERE s.session_id='$id' and s.session_id=n1.hon1_id and n1.hon1_id=n2.hon2_id and n2.hon2_id=n3.hon3_id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION`, just listen to your query, all subqueries should have the same amount of columns.

```
(SELECT spmbmbme_name, present, absent, leave_sick, business FROM namespmember1 WHERE hon1_id = '$id')
UNION
(SELECT spmbmbme_name, present, absent, leave_sick, business FROM namespmember2 WHERE hon2_id =  '$id')
UNION
(SELECT spmbmbme_name, present, absent, leave_sick, business FROM namespmember3 WHERE hon3_id = '$id')
```